# How to write to a text file and save it for multiple uses

Tags: java, android, save

So far I have made a text file in my assets folder and I can read it fine and does what it is supposed to do. When I write to it using the following:

```
 FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE); 
 fos.write(("0").getBytes());
 fos.close()
```

it works. However when I close my app and reopen it later, it does not remember anything I changed it to.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Files in assets or raw are intended to be read-only, so copy it to a new location (like in `Environment.getDataDirectory()`) and then you should be able to write to it.

---

I would think this would throw some type of exception do you have an empty catch block? At a minimum you should use `e.printStackTrack()` otherwise your app will silently fail...

```
try {
    FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE); 
    fos.write(("0").getBytes());
    fos.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but where would I move it to?

Comment: You have a number of choices, like `getFilesDir()` or `getDir()` in the "Other Useful Methods" subsection of [Data Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal).

Comment: Thanks again, but now i have no clue on how to put it into the Environment.getDataDirectory()... If you could give me an example that would be great... I just did a quick google search and couldn't find what i was looking for... Thanks again so far you have helped me a lot!!

Comment: I found this answer: [Android: How to copy files in 'assets' to sdcard?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11212942/1267661). Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Thanks so much I am going to try that now

Answer (score 0):

I think you just forget to call flush after writting

```
FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE); 
 fos.write(("0").getBytes());
 fos.flush();
 fos.close();
```